# Does express.Router() require an export to work? The second parameter of app.use() doesn't seem to be able to be hard-coded and only works if imported

Tags: node.js, express

I am following a coding book and ran into an issue with express.Router(). I am new to express as I mainly use React.

My question is, when routing, I have used:

```
import express from 'express'
import users from './api/users.route.js'

const app = express()

const router = express.Router()

//use route
app.use("/api/v1/users", router.route('/').get((req, res) => res.end('Test Users')))

export default app
```

I want to focus on the below code for a second.

```
app.use("/api/v1/users", router.route('/').get((req, res) => res.end('Test Users')))
```

So basically the code above is throwing an error of

```
Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a Object
```

Now what's interesting is if I write just the second parameter in app.use() (see below)

```
router.route('/').get((req, res) => res.end('Test Users'))
```

and grab it from a file that has been exported as router

```
import express from 'express'

const router = express.Router()

router.route('/').get((req, res) => res.end('Test Users!'))

export default router
```

and then import it and use it in the 2nd parameter of app.use() like this (users is the 'router' in export default router)

```
app.use("/api/v1/users", users)
```

all of a sudden the code works.

Just to reiterate, what I'm basically saying is

```
app.use("/api/v1/users", users)
```

works. But...

```
app.use("/api/v1/users", router.route('/').get((req, res) => res.end('Test Users')))
```

does not work...

Why?

Comment: You need to pass the router in, `router.route('/').get()` returns something completely different.

Comment: What do you mean pass it in? Pass it in where?

Comment: In `app.use()`.

Comment: @tkausl But what I'm not understanding is when I pass in the exported router into app.use() like >> app.use("/api/v1/users", exportedRouter) << how is that any different than >> app.use("/api/v1/users", router.route('/').get((req, res) => res.end('Test Users'))) <<

Comment: @tkausl it's literally the same line of code being exported and put into app.use()

Comment: No, its not. One passes `router` to `app.use`, the other one passes the result of the function call to `app.use`. This has nothing to do with exporting and importing, the only difference is calling `router.route().get()` on one line __and then__ passing `router` to `app.use` vs. passing `router.route().get()` to `app.use`.

Comment: @tkausl Okay, that makes a little more sense. So is it possible to write it out long ways in the second parameter of app.use()? If so how would you write it in this scenario? Like basically how would I make it work without importing the result from router